# C# RotateTransform - problems changing center

Tags: c#, msdn, rotatetransform

In my C# program I am using the RotateTransform Method do rotate the picture that I want to draw. 
This is already working, but I can't find out how I could change the centerpoint from where the picture rotates.
At default it's the bottom left corner of my Picturebox, unfortunately I need to rotate around another point at (760, 480) px.

I've searched everywhere and only came across this CenterX property.
[CenterX msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.centerx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Anyway, I don't seem to find this property with Visual Studio, 
so I guess I'm doing this wrong.

My current code looks like this:

```
*e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, physicObj.lineStartingPoint, physicObj.lineEndingPoint);
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(physicObj.leftCornerCircle, physicObj.circleSize));
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Rectangle(physicObj.leftCornerRectangle, physicObj.rectangleSize));*
```

This part is working fine but uses a wrong center point to rotate around.
I have tried to use

```
e.Graphics.RotateTransform.CenterX = ... ;
```

But there seems to be no CenterX accessible within e.Graphics.RotateTransform.
Visual Studio displays a red line beneath RotateTransform saying it is a method, which is not valid in the given context.
I don't know the way to set this property and I haven't found any coding examples doing so, and based on the info that Microsoft gives (in the link) I thought this was the way to do it.

Hopefully someone can explain what I need to do to change this center point.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw line rotated at an angle over bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015098/draw-line-rotated-at-an-angle-over-bitmap) One more example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035558/degree-rotation-on-triangle-without-changing-position-using-c-sharp-windows-appl/36039553#36039553) - In sort use use the Graphics.TranslateTranform beore and after the roation, then draw.. - `CenterX` is from Media, i.e. WPF; I assume you are doing WInForms

Comment: You also need to learn some language basics. It does not make sense to treat a method like a property.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple:
1. translate to the center
2. rotate
3. translate back

```
float centerX = 760;
float centerY = 480;
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-centerX, -centerY);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(centerX, centerY);
```

Essentially, you create 3 matrices and multiply them to achieve the result - a single transformation matrix, the basics of 2D and 3D transformations.

P.S. you can create an extension method for convenience:

```
public static class GraphicsExtensions
{
  public static void TranslateTransform(this Graphics g, float x, float y, float angle)
  {
    g.TranslateTransform(-x, -y);
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    g.TranslateTransform(x, y);
  }
}
```